vba force immediate screen paint on change event before long running function
I have a fairly long running function that retrieves some information from 3rd party sources when the user changes the value in a combo box.  Everything is working, but what I am seeing is that the dropdown stays open until the function completes, then the dropdown closes.  I would like to have the dropdown close, then the function runs.
This is VBA. My code is in the change event of the combobox.  I have tried several things, none have been effective.

I have tried a me.repaint first thing in the change event prior to calling the function.
have tried a me.repaint with a doevents after
I have tried a me.repaint with a sleep after
I have tried moving the code to the AfterUpdate method, but that requires the user change focus first.
I have tried me.refreshscreen

None of the above work.  Is there another way to do this?  I just want the dropdown to close prior to running the function.  I have a status text field that explains what it is doing, but the dropdown overlays it somewhat since it is not closing.

this is actually for vba running under outlook on a userform.
